# What do the user CPU time and system CPU time in getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &r_usage) measure excactly?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, getrusage

So I am trying to know the time the current thread has been executing for so far. I am trying to use `getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &r_usage);` for it. Here are my confusions:

1- Will the time returned by the this function include the time the threads spent being blocked (e.g. on a condition variable) or scheduled out?

2- How about the time the thread spent being blocked for other reasons e.g. blocked for I/O?

3- Can I increase the time accuracy to make `getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &r_usage);`to return it in nanoseconds?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you need nanosecond precision? Context switch takes couple of microseconds, so you already have a error of microsecond magnitude due to CSWs

Comment: FYI, if your kernel have `CONFIG_SCHED_DEBUG` set, you may try to check `sum_exec_runtime` in `/proc/sched_debug` for your thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general the blocked time won't be assigned to user or kernel CPU time (which is what rusage measures). The `rusage` timer is basically a "wall clock timer" that is started and stopped by the OS: when the process is scheduled it notes the time and when it is descheduled it stops it (a similarly for the user/kernel split on entry/exit to kernel routines). The sum of all those segments is CPU time.

In some cases, like IO, the kernel might be doing real work, not waiting and that may be assigned to your process.

If you want higher precious for *CPU time* you should look into performance counters. On Linux you can use the `perf_events` system to access these counters in a virtualized way, or use a library like [PAPI](http://icl.utk.edu/papi/) that wraps access to this subsystem, or perhaps easiest to get started is to use something lightweight like libpfc which provides straightforward counter access.

You also ask:

> Moreover, how can I include the time spent on I/O?

This is a tough question because of the asynchronous and cached nature of IO on modern systems. It is tough to pin down exactly the time spent and how to allocate it (e.g., if one process brings a page from disk into the cache but then 10 other processes subsequently access it, how do you divide up the IO time)? One think you could do is look into the `/proc/pid/` counters and status entries which probably has a blocking-on-IO indicator. Indeed, `top` can show processes in this state, so you could likely get this into from `/proc/$pid`. Note that you would have to sample this file system from some other thread to make that work, I think.

Alternately, you could try to instrument, at the application level, your IO calls. Finally, you could use something like `ptrace` or the newer `FTrace` on Linux to instrument at the kernel level the IO calls, and you can probably filter this by process. Newer kernels apparently have "per-process IO accounting" - but I couldn't quickly dig up a good link. Probably the source for `iotop` would have the calls you need though.

Finally, it all depends on what you mean by *the time the current thread has been executing for so far*: if you want to include IO, perhaps you just want the wall-clock time since the thread started? Then you can use `clock_gettime` and friends, which offer nanosecond resolution (nominally, but the call itself takes at least a dozen nanoseconds, so you aren't going to measure things that take 1 or 2 nanos accurately).

Answer (score 3):

It seems hard to believe that time spent blocked (for whatever reason) would be charged as time spent executing--but on the off chance that it is, let's do a quick experiment to get an idea:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, timeval const &t) {
    return os << t.tv_sec << '.' << std::setw(6) << std::setfill('0') << t.tv_usec << std::setfill(' ');
}

int main() {
    rusage r;

    getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &r);
    std::cout << r.ru_utime << " [" << r.ru_stime << "]\n";
    sleep(10);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &r);
    std::cout << r.ru_utime << " [" << r.ru_stime << "]\n";
}
```

Result:

```
0.000000 [0.000000]
0.000000 [0.000000]
```

So, time spent sleeping isn't charged. We can do a similar test with a mutex:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std::literals;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, timeval const &t) {
    return os << t.tv_sec << '.' << std::setw(6) << std::setfill('0') << t.tv_usec << std::setfill(' ');
}

int main() {
    rusage r;

    getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &r);
    std::cout << r.ru_utime << " [" << r.ru_stime << "]\n" << std::flush;

    std::mutex m;
    m.try_lock();   // ensure mutex is locked

    // create thread to unlock mutex after 5 seconds:
    auto t = std::thread([&]{ std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s); m.unlock(); });

    // wait for mutex to be unlocked
    m.lock();

    // re-check resource usage
    getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &r);
    std::cout << r.ru_utime << " [" << r.ru_stime << "]\n";
    t.join();
}
```

This gives similar results. I haven't bothered to repeat it for a condition variable, but I'd be quite surprised to see different results with it (a condvar is always associated with a mutex, and it's the mutex you really wait for).

It's less practical to try to test every possible kind of I/O, but past experience indicates that the same is true with it: time blocked waiting for I/O is not treated as time executing.

As far as accuracy goes, I suppose you *could* theoretically improve accuracy to the nanosecond range, but it would involve rewriting the kernel, not just flipping a switch or calling a different function. Realistically, it's open to a lot of question whether you'd be able to get *much* more accurate even then. If you need nanosecond level precision, this probably isn't the right kind of tool for the job.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer with code. Can you recommend another tool for nanosecond range? Or any other way, you think is better, to do this job? Moreover, how can I include the time spent on I/O?

Comment: @DIMIA: Have you tried using a profiler (e.g., `g++ -pg foo.cpp`, then `gprof a.out`? Fair warning: it will take some time and effort to learn to use this well.

Comment: Actually I am writing a profiler myself and this is part of the calculations I make.